# Getting an error when trying to run my last method

Tags: java, methods

My program requires me to create 4 methods. 1 to take in length, 1 to take width, and 1 to calculate the area, and 1 to display the area. My code seems to be working up till the final method where i need to display my area. I've tried pretty much almost everything i can think of but it still isn't working.

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Lab9Q2
    {
      public static double getLength()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);          // Create Method
        System.out.println ("Enter the length of the rectange"); // ask for the length 
        double length = keyboard.nextDouble();
        return length;
      }

      public static double getWidth()
      {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);          // Create Method
        System.out.println ("Enter the width of the rectange"); // ask for the width
        double width = keyboard.nextDouble();
        return width;
      }

      public static double getArea (double length, double width)
      {
        double area; 
        area = length*width;
        return area; 
      }
      public static double displayArea (double length, double width, double area)
      {
        System.out.println ("The length is: " + length);
        System.out.println ("The width is: " + width);
        System.out.println ("The area of the rectangle is: " + area);
      }
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
      getLength();
      getWidth();
      displayArea(length, width, area);
    }
    }
```

The program should use all my method calls and then display the results properly but it wont do so.

Comment: length, width, area parameters are not defined for `displayArea` method.

Comment: Bsed upon this the code should not even compile.

Comment: What is it, that you "can think of" but does not work?
@ScaryWombat would have been easier to guess, if the post had contained kind of an error message or so, right? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You probably intended to use the three results from the helper methods in the final call to `displayArea()`:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    double length = getLength();
    double width = getWidth();
    double area = getArea(length, width);
    displayArea(length, width, area);
}
```

Comment: not sure why the answer that seems a copy-and-paste of your fine answer got an upvote

Answer (score 1):

Change the `main` block as below

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
  double length = getLength();
  double width = getWidth();
  double area  = getArea(length, width);
  displayArea(length, width, area);
}
```

You missed the assignments and calling `getArea` function

Answer (score 0):

Two ways you can get your code working

1) change your main method as

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
double length = getLength();
double width = getWidth();
double area = getArea(length, width);
displayArea(length, width, area);
}
```

2) Declare your length,width,area globally.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Lab9Q2
{
  public static double length;
  public static double width;
  public static double area;

  public static void getLength()
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);          // Create Method
    System.out.println ("Enter the length of the rectange"); // ask for the length 
    length = keyboard.nextDouble();

  }

  public static void getWidth()
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);          // Create Method
    System.out.println ("Enter the width of the rectange"); // ask for the width
    width = keyboard.nextDouble();

  }

  public static void getArea (double length, double width)
  {
    area = length*width;

  }
  public static double displayArea (double length, double width, double area)
  {
    System.out.println ("The length is: " + length);
    System.out.println ("The width is: " + width);
    System.out.println ("The area of the rectangle is: " + area);
  }
public static void main (String [] args)
{
  getLength();  //Here length will get initialised
  getWidth();   //Here width will get initialised
  getArea();   //Here area will get calculated ..you also missed this statement
  displayArea(length, width, area);
}
}
```

Comment: `return length;` - why?

Comment: Also why static?

Comment: yes actually..no need to return..static method access only static variable

Comment: so don't do it, just confuses people

Comment: Removed return statements

Comment: you have to change the methods' signatures

Comment: Done :)..anything else?